# Extjs 4 Row-editting canceledit event not fired

Tags: plugins, extjs4

I am using Extjs 4 with Designer 1.2.0. I am using Row Editing Plugin within the grid Panel.
I have observed that **canceledit** Event is not fired on the row-editor. 
What could be the best possible solution for that ?

Any Suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in extjs 4 row editing plugin doesn't have an event for canceledit. In extjs 4 stores are closely related to grids so if you cancel edit for the record in cause is caller reject() and the store doesn't change...

Comment: When i click on cancel button, a new record still gets displayed ( though not inserted )... how to avoid that ? any workaround ? Also, what abt cancelEdit() ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,
in your grid panel view:

```
 this.myRowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {clicksToEdit: 2});
 this.myRowEditing.on({
     scope: this,
      canceledit: function(pRoweditor, pChanges) {
         this.fireEvent('canceledit', pRoweditor, pChanges);
         ....
      }
  });
```

This is the solution I found to catch the 'canceledit' event from a controller.